# How to echo text in a file and delete previous content?

Tags: linux, echo

I would like the previous content in the file to be deleted and only new content to be visible.

Comment: Simply use the `>` redirect operator in your command, which will overwrite the contents of file.

Comment: [How to overwrite file using echo?](https://superuser.com/q/414465/173513)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo 'new contents' >file
```

This will truncate (empty) the file named `file` before `echo` inserts the string `new contents` into it (assuming that the file is writable by the current user and that it's not a directory).